# how to run custom code after validation of mvc4 unobtrusive validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive

i am looking of the a way to run custom code after validation of mvc4 unobtrusive validation functionality i have found a lot but nothing works for me 
try this

```
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    var oldErrorFunction = settngs.errorPlacement;
    var oldSucessFunction = settngs.success;
    settngs.errorPlacement = function (error, inputElement) {
        $(inputElement).closest('.fieldset').addClass('fieldset-validation-error')
        oldErrorFunction(error, inputElement);
        myadditionalfunction();
    }
    settngs.success = function (error) {
        $(error).closest('.fieldset').removeClass('fieldset-validation-error')
        oldSucessFunction(error);
        myadditionalfunction();
    }
```

didn't work
i also tried

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        invalidHandler: function (form) {
            myadditionalfunction();
        }
    });
```

also didn't work and i am going crazy if u have fixed it please let me know

my custom functions will not hit!

Comment: Why couldn't you just call the form's validate function (`$frm.validate()`), check if it's valid (`$frm.isvalid()`) then run your custom code afterwards?

Comment: this will not work on blur/key up of fields. as the validation currently works.